Automatic Module present but not found
In my Java 21 project, I'm trying to use the package io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts in the library jjwt-api.
This dependency has no module-info.java and no Automatic-Module-Name-entry inside of the MANIFEST.MF.
IntelliJ 2024.1.3 suggests it requires jjwt-api, and if I run:
import java.lang.module.ModuleFinder;
import java.nio.file.Path;

ModuleFinder.of(Path.of("C:\\Users\\...\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\io.jsonwebtoken\\jjwt-api\\0.12.5\\ea8243e36f16c2834ad69a048ed8a24aa9dd3e79\\jjwt-api-0.12.5.jar"))
            .findAll()
            .forEach(System.out::println);

It also finds and suggests that name (following the spec).
The Problem
If I try to compile my application, I get the error:
Fehler: Modul nicht gefunden: jjwt.api
    requires jjwt.api;
                 ^

(German for: "Error: Module not found")
build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.12.5")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.5")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-gson:0.12.5")
}

Question
Is this an IntelliJ, Gradle, or Javac error, and how can I fix it?

How can I use this package / require that module?

I have no experiences with Gradle but somehow, it looks natural to me that when you declare a dependency as “runtimeOnly”, it won’t be resolved at compile-time, therefore, the compiler error would be expected.

I have now fixed the error by using the extra-java-module-info plugin.
I simply added the following lines to my build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    // other plugins
    id("org.gradlex.extra-java-module-info") version "1.8"
}

extraJavaModuleInfo {
    deriveAutomaticModuleNamesFromFileNames.set(true)
}

(I won't accept this as the answer tho, as I hope that there is a better, more "native" way of doing including automatic modules without the use of external gradle plugins)

The "better" way is to convince the authors of this library to include a module-info.class. Having an Automatic-Module-Name might be an option to, but this might not work if your code also needs to reference classes from one of the other dependencies.

That's what one of the discussions on the Gradle forum leads to.
